# JMS - Browsing queue messages before they are consumed by consumer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel, message-queue

I have to browse messages from a message queue before they are consumed by consumers. (using `activemq` as broker)

There are some consumers waiting for the message in the queue.

I have to browse the message and using that message info I have to perform some work but the problem is messages are consumed as soon as they come in queue.

Is there any way to get an alert as soon as message comes in the queue and to ensure that messages are browsed before they are actually consumed by other consumers?

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQMessageConsumer.html  use MessageListener

Comment: What do you want to achieve? While there is a technical solution, it seems that the design could be altered to fit better on JMS: Either using a selector, separate queues for each client, an (additional) topic etc.

Comment: We have multiple applications communicating with each other using message queues. I have to intercept their messages and need to extract message information without doing any changes in current application system.

Comment: @lambardar I've updated my answer considering your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read about [composite destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) of ActiveMQ. Using the composite destinations you can make a message to be routed to multiple destinations. You can have a combination of queue and topics in a virtual destination. ActiveMQ will route messages based on the values defined in `<forwardTo>` attribute. So for the pattern you are trying to implement, the normal consumer will receive messages from one queue and the browser from another topic. This way both will get the same message data.

Please have a look at the example given in the [link](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me in figuring out my soltution.

Comment: Best possible solution is to either use composite queues or use mirrored queue. I would prefer composite queues over mirror as in case of composite, we can create selective queues' copies but in case of mirror, broker will create copies of each queue(couldn't find a way to mirror selective queues) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **queue browser**, possibly using a **message selector**:

```
this.queueBrowser = getQueueSession().createBrowser(getQueue(),
        selector);
```

A selector is like a "where clause" for selecting messages.

**Update**

If you have **one queue** with a "normal" consumer, and you like to browse the queue *before* the real consumer consumes the message. If the real consumer consumes first, your browser won't see the message. That's **not reliable**.

Therefore you should use **two queues**. Your browsing application acts as a "man in the middle" or like a **bridge**, it will always get all messages posted into the 1st queue, and it has to send it on a 2nd queue. The real consumer is connecting to the 2nd queue. So both consume normally.

Another possibility is to **change the sender**: It could send the message **on two queues**, one for the real consumer, one for your browsing application only.

Comment: Upvote for the first option [two queues]. It provides a reliable solution and flexibility to add any additional processing without impact to the producer or the end consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Two queues option was the one i was looking for but didn't have clarity how to achieve this without affecting sender and consumer application. But now got the solution, ActiveMQ provides functionality(Composite and Mirrored queues) using which broker itself creates copies of the original queue.